# How to check if an xml node has children in python with minidom?

Tags: python, xml, minidom

How to check if an xml node has children in python with minidom?

I'm writing an recursive function to remove all attributes in an xml file and I need to check if an node has child nodes before calling the same function again.

What I've tried:
I tried to use node.childNodes.length, but didn't have much luck. Any other suggestions?

Thanks

My Code:

```
    def removeAllAttributes(dom):
        for node in dom.childNodes:
            if node.attributes:
                for key in node.attributes.keys():
                    node.removeAttribute(key)
            if node.childNodes.length > 1:
                node = removeAllAttributes(dom)
        return dom
```

Error code:
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in an infinite loop.  Here is your problem line:

```
            node = removeAllAttributes(dom)
```

I think you mean

```
            node = removeAllAttributes(node)
```

Comment: Good call! That fixed it! I would up vote your answer but i don't have enough rep :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try [`hasChildNodes()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html#xml.dom.Node.hasChildNodes) - although if inspecting the childNodes attribute directly isn't working you may have other problems.

On a guess, your processing is being thrown off because your element has no element children, but does have text children or something.  You can check for that this way:

```
def removeAllAttributes(element):
    for attribute_name in element.attributes.keys():
        element.removeAttribute(attribute_name)
    for child_node in element.childNodes:
        if child_node.nodeType == xml.dom.minidom.ELEMENT_NODE:
            removeAllAttributes(child_node)
```

Comment: Just tried that, I got the same error code:  RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: Yeah, you need to inspect the type of the child nodes.  See the edited version.